# How to design multi-tenant database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I don't have a coding question but more of a structure related one.

If I had a site that say for example allowed a user to sign up, login, and manage finances, or a family photobook or whatever. (the job that the front end is performing is irrelevant) If I have multiple users registering and creating there own accounts then what would be the correct way to store that data?
I assume you would not have a single table with different users data together so would it be proper to create a single table for user logins then automatically create a new table exclusive to each new user that would then hold the data related to there personal login?

Take an online check book for example, I would have a table that manages user logins then during the registration process it would automatically create a table for that user to hold all the data entries for their own check book. Is that correct? What if the data requires multiple tables to manage one particular users data?

Comment: `"create a new table exclusive to each new user"` - No.  Emphatic no.  In every way no.  Do not create a new table *per record* in another table.  Structure your tables by the entities you're modeling.

Comment: Thanks David! So users table, transactions table, etc... got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do ***not*** create a table for each user, create one table that is keyed by the user's unique identifier and put all user's data into it. You can create one such table for each logical set of information however. E.g., a `users` table with user information, a `posts` table with blog posts made by the user, a `friends` table that links users together.

Keep this in mind -- day-to-day operation of your application should ***never*** require changes to the database schema (like CREATE TABLE), only row manipulation operations (like INSERT and UPDATE.) [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is a good place to start reading up on the subject.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. So I would have say a user name in the users table that could be matched to all transactions that have a matching user name in a cell located in a transactions table. Also thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, that is the basic concept. In particular, you generally want to reference by the user id (a unique integer assigned to each user) instead of the actual username (a string) because it's smaller and less prone to trouble if the user changes username.